# Is there a way to achieve Flutter staggered grid view in Android native?

Tags: android, flutter, android-recyclerview

Flutter has a staggered grid view like this in the image, but it supports different width and height, is there a way to achieve the same thing in android?

[image]

Comment: https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-as-staggered-grid-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, staggered gridview is an extension of GridView.
You can learn about staggered gridview from [this](http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-productive-android-developer-part-6-staggered-gridview/).
[image]

Comment: I know about StaggeredLayoutManager but I want to change the span size dynamically